# Python pip error when installing anything - Mac OSX Mavericks.

Tags: python, pip

Problem when I try to use pip for installs that are preventing me from adding new packages. I previously updated my default Mac OSX Mavericks version from 2.7 to 3.4 (Anaconda) then removed Anaconda.

I  This is the error message I get.

```
   Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/4c/znnkwgfj68l4665x2_h5lb200000gn/T/pip_build_user/dom/setup.py';
exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/4c/znnkwgfj68l4665x2_h5lb200000gn/T/pip-UjquQV-
record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/4c/znnkwgfj68l4665x2_h5lb200000gn/T/pip_build_user/dom
    Storing debug log for failure in /Users/user/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

Comment: try this first: `$ pip install --upgrade setuptools`

Comment: Have you examined that log file?

Comment: Here's what it says - does this suggest an issue with virtualenv? skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-0.8.1-py2.4.egg#md5=fa8831295f1073151876375c4567f5cd (from https://pypi.python$
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-0.8.2-py2.4.egg#md5=4a92b99c93026031b7298906bf126ccd (from https://pypi.python$
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-0.8.3-py2.4.egg#md5=fbcb29d72e35ee93d80738d46e69d350 (from https://pypi.python$
    Skipping link